# Transition functions for locally free sheaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

The following is from Vakil's notes.

> Given a locally free sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ with rank $n$, and a trivializing open neighborhood of $\mathcal{F}$ (an open cover $\{U_i\}$ such that over each $U_i$, $\mathcal{F}|_{U_i} \cong \mathcal{O}^{\oplus n}_{U_i}$ as $\mathcal{O}$-modules) we have transition functions $g_{ij} :U_i \cap U_j \to \text{GL}(n,\mathcal{O}(U_i \cap U_j))$.

Can someone elaborate how these transition functions arise? I understand that we have two different isomorphisms $\varphi_i : \mathcal{F}|_{U_i\cap U_j} \to \mathcal{O}^{\oplus n}_{U_i \cap U_j}$ and $\varphi_j:\mathcal{F}|_{U_i\cap U_j} \to \mathcal{O}^{\oplus n}_{U_i \cap U_j}$ and we can consider the composition $$\varphi_i \circ \varphi^{-1}_j : \mathcal{O}^{\oplus n}_{U_i \cap U_j} \to \mathcal{O}^{\oplus n}_{U_i \cap U_j}$$ but this is a morphism of sheaves and I think that these $g_{ij}$ are maps from $U_i \cap U_j$ so we need to consider $\varphi_i \circ \varphi^{-1}_j$ at the level of sections or something? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For our purpose, the indexed open cover doesn't matter so, for now, let's just work on an open subset $U \subset X$.

Then, $GL_n(\mathcal{O}(U))$ is an affine scheme, isomorphic to $\operatorname{Spec} A$ where $$A = \mathcal{O}(U)[x_{11}, x_{12} \dots, x_{nn}]_{\operatorname{det}(x_{ij})}.$$ As such, to give a map $U \to GL_n(\mathcal{O}(U))$ it is equivalent to give a map $A \to \mathcal{O}(U)$.

If $\mathcal{O}^{\oplus n}_{U} \to \mathcal{O}^{\oplus n}_{U}$ is an isomorphism it then gives an isomorphism of $\mathcal{O}(U)$-modules $\psi: \mathcal{O}(U)^{\oplus n} \to \mathcal{O}(U)^{\oplus n}$. Being a map of free modules, it admits a matrix form $\psi = (\psi_{ij})$,
with $\psi_{ij} \in \mathcal{O}(U)$, so that $\det(\psi_{ij})$ is a unit in $\mathcal{O}(U)$. By the universal property of localization, the map sending $x_{ij} \mapsto \psi_{ij}$ induces a ring homomorphism $A \to \mathcal{O}(U)$, as required.